# How to create an NSMutableArray Dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I want to create an array with the name the user has given as input in textfield, for this i want to know how to create an array dynamically.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: For what reason you need to do so? a name of an array is just a name used by system, your user won't be able to see it anyway. In your case, if you wanna create an array dynamically, name it whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a dynamic variable name, then the only way you can sort of accomplish this is by creating the array and then storing it in a dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myArrays;//declared and initialized somewhere

NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArrays addObject:newArray forKey:someLabel.text];
```

Comment: I want array to be declared and initialized dynamically (while the app is running)

Comment: what do you need to store in that array?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically declare an array, but you can never use an input string as a name of your object's array.

Say what is you target, and we could help you to solve it. It looks like you want do do something and you are taking the wrong approach, if you have such request.

Comment: http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=3175395&username=demo... I want ot store values found under each geoname in each different array. I dont know how to do it. thatswhy i planned to create the array dynmaically to store the values of all tags found under geoname

Comment: so it is just a string containing xml? all you need is an NSMutableDictionary, where the key will be user's input (as you said) and the value will be the xml string. And you don't need any arrays.

Comment: Of course I got it! The question is: did YOU get it? Accept if "yes". Ask if more data needed.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that "U got what im trying to say" This is what i thought "so it is just a string containing xml? all you need is an NSMutableDictionary, where the key will be user's input (as you said) and the value will be the xml string. And you don't need any arrays." as you said